# Compiler gcc:error; no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc

I am extremely new to programming and I am having problems with the basic starting program of, 'hello, world'.

I have downloaded MinGW and I believe I set it up correctly with the command promt by entering: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin"`

Then I created this code following a guide while using Notepad++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  puts("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

saving it under `c:/code/c/hello.c`

When I try to compile it or run it under: `gcc -o hello hello.c`, I get this error

```
gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

And I am not sure how to fix this. I have tried looking around, but I cant find any answers or I just don't understand them.

Comment: its `#include <stdio.h>`. It means standard input output.

Comment: Looks a lot like you ran `gcc -o hello hello.c` somewhere where `hello.c` didn't exist - did you try `cd c:/code/c` first?

Answer (score 3):

> gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

Means that `gcc` is unable to find your `hello.c` source file. You should either cd to the source folder:

```
c:
cd c:\code\c\
gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
```

Or use a full path to the source in the command line:

```
gcc -o c:\code\c\hello.exe c:\code\c\hello.c
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, but I am still having trouble. I tried using the full path, but that did not end up working. For thing first think you offered I tried typing that up in the command promt and that didn't seem to work either. I think I am doing something really wrong.